# Angle made by orbital with y-axis

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

What is the hybridization and angle (in degrees) with respect to the y-axis for the following hybrid orbital $ψ=\frac{1}{√3}c×(s-\frac{1}{√3}×p_x+\frac{√3}{√2}×p_y)$
The answer given is 30 degrees but I couldn't figure out how.I was able to figure out that it is an $sp^2$ hybrid orbital wavefunction.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to read, because  there is an open parenthesis before s - 1, and it is not closed

Comment: This orbital isn't normalised, even though you seem to have included what appear to be intended as normalisation factors. Also, $x/y\times z$ is pretty ambiguous: do you mean $x/(yz)$ or $(x/y)z$?, and even though one can guess which it is (since it makes little sense to divide by an orbital), you shouldn't write that way. My suggestion: use `$$\frac{a}{b}c$$`, it's far clearer (and prettier): $$\frac{a}{b}c$$

Comment: the orbital is normalized. if we add the squares of the coefficients of s,px and py orbitals, it adds up to 1

Comment: Well, now that you've added some constant $c$, then yes it is obviously normalised as long as you choose the right $c$: but if that $c$ weren't there, then I count $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{17}{18}.$$

Comment: It seems like someone was trying hard to get 30 degrees.  1/sqrt(3) is the tangent of 30 degrees, and sqrt(3)/2 is the cosine...